# tar and tee command, md5sum on the fly

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tar, tee

Why is creating an archive like :

`tar -p -c -f - --acls file1 | tee mybackup.tar | md5sum`

give a different checksum than doing md5sum on this same archive, doing :

`tar --to-command=md5sum -x -f mybackup.tar` (This is the same as `tar -x -f mybackup.tar -O | md5sum`)

The objective here is to catch md5sum on stdout while doing the archiving. Avoiding me to "dry-run" a tar only for md5sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `tar --to-command=md5sum -x -f mybackup.tar` md5sums the extracted files, not the tar archive itself.

Doing `cat mybackup.tar | md5sum` is the right way to compare the checksum.